# iphone utility application tutorial

Tags: iphone

I'm very new to iPhone development.  I want to create a utility application much like the weather app (enter zip codes for cities to track the weather).  The weather app allows users to scroll through their favorite places.  There's a flip side where you can manage your selections.  I am looking for a tutorial on how to create a similar type app.  Can anyone point me to a good tutorial for utility iphone apps please?  I've been googling and can't find what I'm looking for.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, Xcode has a Utility Application template.

Comment: yes, thank you.  I've found the template, just looking for a tutorial for how to get started with the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](http://www.edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/iphone/taschenlampe/)?  I found it by googling "iphone utility application tutorial".  You should do that next time. :)